# Unable to create duplicate list from existing list using list comprehension with an if condition

Tags: python, list, if-statement, list-comprehension

I have a sorted list with duplicate elements like

```
>>> randList = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]
>>> randList
[1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]
```

I need to create a list that removes the adjacent duplicate elements. I can do it like:

```
>>>> dupList = []
     for num in nums:
       if num not in dupList:
         dupList.append(num)
```

But I want to do it with list comprehension. I tried the following code:

```
>>> newList = []
>>> newList = [num for num in randList if num not in newList]
```

But I get the result like the if condition isn't working.

```
>>> newList
[1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]
```

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks!!

Edit 1: The wording of the question does seem to be confusing given the data I have provided. The for loop that I am using will remove *all* duplicates but since I am sorting the list beforehand, that shouldn't a problem when removing adjacent duplicates.

Comment: Note that your `for` loop based solution will remove ALL duplicates, not only adjacent ones.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers You're right. But since the list is sorted anyway, will it have any impact?

Comment: Well if your list is sorted, duplicates are by definition adjacent indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) is the simplest approach to remove **adjacent** (and only adjacent) duplicates, even for unsorted input:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [k for k, _ in groupby(randList)]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Removing **all** duplicates while maintaining the order of occurence can be efficiently achieved with an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict). This, as well, works for ordered and unordered input:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(randList))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: In a sorted list, all duplicates are adjacent. There's really no need to emphasize this point.

Comment: @jpp When the OP explicitly calls them adjacent despite their sorted data, I shall feel free to cover the general case and mention the distinction.

Comment: OP hasn't defined what he wants with non-sorted lists. I think that's an assumption rather than a generalisation.

Comment: @jpp Hence the attempt to make to make things as clear as possible by pointing out the dfiference between all/adjacent sorted/unsorted. The answer covers the OP's concrete use case while making it clear what the two options do for various input. I don't see how such a generalization harms the answer.

Comment: I've updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51190265/4210388) with a comparison of evaluation time. It turned out that this approach is slower than the set approach. However, this solution is indeed closer to the original question (without the sorting restriction).

Answer (score 1):

## Update: Comparison of different Approaches

There have been three ways of achieving the goal of removing adjacent duplicate elements in a sorted list, i.e. removing all duplicates:

- using `groupby` (only adjacent elements, requires initial sorting)
- using `OrderedDict` (all duplicates removed)
- using `sorted(list(set(_)))` (all duplicaties removed, ordering restored by sorting).

I compared the running times of the different solutions using:

```
from timeit import timeit

print('groupby:', timeit('from itertools import groupby; l = [x // 5 for x in range(1000)]; [k for k, _ in groupby(l)]'))
print('OrderedDict:', timeit('from collections import OrderedDict; l = [x // 5 for x in range(1000)]; list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(l))'))
print('Set:', timeit('l = [x // 5 for x in range(1000)]; sorted(list(set(l)))'))

> groupby: 78.83623623599942
> OrderedDict: 94.54144410200024
> Set: 65.60372123999969
```

Note that the `set` approach is the fastest among all alternatives.

## Old Answer

Python first evaluates the list comprehension and then assigns it to `newList`, so you cannot refer to it during execution of the list comprehension. To illustrate, consider the following code:

```
randList = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]

newList = []
newList = [num for num in randList if print(newList)]

> []
> []
> []
> …
```

This becomes even more evident if you try:

```
# Do not initialize newList2
newList2 = [num for num in randList if print(newList2)]

> NameError: name 'newList2' is not defined
```

You can remove duplicates by turning randList into a set:

```
sorted(list(set(randlist)))

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Be aware that **this does remove *all* duplicates** (not just adjacent ones) and ordering is not preserved. The former also holds true for your proposed solution with the loop.

*edit*: added a `sorted` clause as to specification of required ordering.

Comment: @schwobaseggl, Since the list is sorted as per OP, this shouldn't make a difference. The main point is `set` is unordered, and it appears OP wants ordering maintained.

Comment: @schwobaseggl I pointed that out in the last sentence of my answer. Furthermore, the code given by the OP also has this effect. Also @ jpp: It seems unclear what the OP wants since the 'working code' reaches a different goal than he describes.

Comment: @schwobaseggl I updated my answer with a comparison of the three solutions

Answer (score 1):

> I need to create a list that removes the adjacent duplicate elements

Note that your `for` loop based solution will remove ALL duplicates, not only adjacent ones. Test it with this:

```
rand_list = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 5, 1]
```

according to your spec the result should be:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5, 1]
```

but you'll get

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

instead.

A working solution to only remove *adjacent* duplicates is to use a generator:

```
def dedup_adjacent(seq):
    prev = seq[0]
    yield prev
    for current in seq[1:]:
        if current == prev:
            continue
        yield current
        prev = current

rand_list = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 5, 1]
list(dedup_adjacent(rand_list))
```

=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5, 1]

Comment: @schwobaseggl, Since the list is sorted as per OP, this shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: @schwobaseggl I missed this part of the spec indeed (but note that the OP's code did remove all duplicates). Answer changed base on your observation.

Comment: Jup, the sample data and the code did not really match the wording of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Python first evaluates the list comprehension and then assigns it to **newList**, so you cannot refer to it during execution of the list comprehension.

You can remove dublicates in two ways:-
1. Using for loop

```
rand_list = [1,2,2,3,3,4,5]
new_list=[]
for i in rand_list:
    if i not in new_list:
        new_list.append(i)
```

2. Convert list to set,then again convert set to list,and at last sort the new list.
   Since set stores values in any order so when we convert set into list you need to sort the list so that you get the item in ascending order

   `rand_list = [1,2,2,3,3,4,5]
    sets = set(rand_list)
    new_list = list(sets)
    new_list.sort()`

Answer (score 0):

In this line `newList = [num for num in randList if num not in newList]`, at first the `list` will be created in right side then then it will be assigned to newList. That's why every time you check `if num not in newList` returns True. Becasue `newList` remains empty till the assignment.

You can try this:

```
randList = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]
new_list=[]
for i in randList:
    if i not in new_list:
        new_list.append(i)

print(new_list)
```

Comment: This is already in the OP's post, is inefficient for large lists (O(N) lookup time), and will remove all duplicates, not only adjencent ones.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the items in a list comprehension as you go along. The items in a list comprehension are only accessible once the comprehension is completed.

For large lists, checking for membership in a list will be expensive, albeit with minimal memory requirements. Instead, you can append to a `set`:

```
randList = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]

def gen_values(L):
    seen = set()
    for i in L:
        if i not in seen:
            seen.add(i)
            yield i

print(list(gen_values(randList)))

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

This algorithm has been implemented in the 3rd party `toolz` library. It's also known as the `unique_everseen` recipe in the `itertools` docs:

```
from toolz import unique

res = list(unique(randList))
```

Answer (score -2):

Since your list is sorted, using `set` will be the fasted way to achieve your goal, as follows:

```
>>> randList = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]
>>> randList
[1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]
>>> remove_dup_list = list(set(randList))
>>> remove_dup_list
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>>
```

Comment: `set` is defined as an __unordered__ collection (at least until python 3.7), so this might loose the ordering. Also, it will removfe all duplicates, not only adjacent ones.

Comment: He is mentioning that the list is sorted so the elements will always be in order, right?

Comment: I repeat: `set` are NOT ordered (at least until py3.7) so the fact that the list is initially sorted is irrelevant (wrt/ keeping the original order at least).  Try this in python 2 or python 3 < 3.7 with `"aaaabbbccc"` as the source sequence, you'll get either `['a', 'c', 'b']` (py2.7.6) or `['c', 'b', 'a']` (py3.4.3).